# convert to binary in SQL shows "???"

Tags: sql-server

I am converting text to binary in SQL from asp.net application. I found a conversion in my table and when I converted it back to var-char in SQL then it showed "Fz123456????????????". Now I am wondering from where these question marks have come from? Is there any character that was inserted which made these ???? to append with password? I am confused. Below is the image attached.

[image]

Comment: If this is converting the `Password` column to text, then character `3F` is a question mark, and it does indeed seem to be repeated there. Whatever caused those question marks to appear acted *before* your attempt to recover text.

Answer (score 1):

> ...I converted it back to var-char...

Use nvarchar

Comment: Looking at the OPs image, I think they're converting the `Password` column to text - the question marks are already there in the binary.

Comment: yes it is already in the binary. I don't know which character caused this. I have to find that character